# gson.toJson declares multiple JSON fields named XX

Tags: java, android, gson

I have one single custom object of type A and an ArrayList containing custom objects of type B that I want to store in my Shared Preferences with gson. Object A worked without problems but when I try to store the list of object B or even just one instance of B, the following error message occurs:

```
2019-01-07 13:05:21.610 28295-28295/com.example.aev.quizzle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aev.quizzle, PID: 28295
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aev.quizzle/com.example.aev.quizzle.activities.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
    at com.example.aev.quizzle.activities.MapsActivity.generateThemes(MapsActivity.java:592)
    at com.example.aev.quizzle.activities.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:164)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

I store the Array List like this:

```
themes = new ArrayList<>();
themes.add(new Theme(0, this));
themes.add(new Theme(1, this));
themes.add(new Theme(2, this));

String jsonTheme = gson.toJson(themes);
prefsEditor.putString("themes", jsonTheme);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And my class Theme looks like this:

```
public class Theme implements Parcelable {
    public ImageView icon;
    public int themeID;
    //public Question[] questions = new Question[14];
    public List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean unlocked;
    Context context;
```

I have seen similar questions with problems with same variable names in superclasses and objects that should be stored, but in my case I do not extend another class in my Theme class.
The error points to the line saying

```
String jsonTheme = gson.toJson(themes);
```

Am I treating the gson object wrong or did I miss anything?

Comment: did you tried using `toJson(Object)` with `toJson(Object, Type)` variant?

Comment: When using any JSON serialization library, you want to only serialize your data or Gson (in this case) will try to convert internal objects that were not designed to be converted, into JSON.  I try to separate objects that I want to convert to JSON from ones that contains unrelated members or mark things I don't want to serialize as `transient`.  I think Gson is serializing ImageView or Context and getting this, can't tell without rest of your code.

Comment: @KaranMer yes it does not make any difference

Comment: @AlexC thankyou very much! Putting transient in front of context and ImageView solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@Transient` is one way to solve this serializing problem. As you might have also noticed after deserializing you need to set these `ImageView` & `Context` to each deserialized `Theme` which might be a small issue.

You could also consider separating your data to be persisted from transient stuff like views & context. Having seen only a small portion of your code your structure could be something like:

Something like:

```
public class Theme {
    public ImageView icon;
    Context context;
    ThemeData themeData

    public Theme(Context contect, ImageView icon, ThemeData themeData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.icon = icon;
        themeData = themeData;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithThemeDataAndViewAndContext() {
        // whatever you need to do in Theme
    }
}
```

where `ThemeData` then contains all the non-transient fields and which you would then persist to `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class ThemeData {
    public int themeID;
    //public Question[] questions = new Question[14];
    public List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean unlocked;
}
```

Note also: I think that if you serialize theme(s) with GSON and save it as a JSON String in `SharedPreferences` you do not need to implement `Parcelable` so I removed it.